# GCM Android Notification not Expanding

Tags: android, notifications, google-cloud-messaging, push

I have implemented GCM for iOS and android both and that part seems to be working fine. My issue is, My notifications on Android are not expandable when text in the notification is more than one line. I have been looking up solutions that suggests to invoke notification using **BigView**. My notifications are directly coming to the device through GCM and I am not editing it in between. I am not sure how to handle this problem.

Should I be just getting data part from notification and invoke notification locally to solve this problem or there is something I can use while sending GCM from server?

EDIT:
I got expanding notification working but it is still not solving my problem because it is showing duplicate notifications. One coming from GCM and second locally invoked notification. I tried applying tag from GCM notification to local one but it isn't solving the issue.

Answer (score 3):

Try to set this style in your notification builder:

```
.setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText("your_message_here"))
```

Comment: I am using direct GCM notification. should I be overriding GcmReceiver class and build notification myself?

Comment: Yes .. That will be a better approach for building our own custom notifications .. And i recommend you to use Firebase Cloud Messaging ..

Comment: It worked but it is showing duplicate notification with GCM. What I wanted to do is overwrite GCM notification with local one even though I applied tag from GCM notification to local notification.

Answer (score 0):

Create notification layout for notification. And then in your textview set 'lines=2' or use 'multiline'.

custom_notification.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:id="@+id/layout"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="10dp" >
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp" />
    <TextView android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/image"
    style="Custom Notification Title" />
 <TextView android:id="@+id/text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/image"
    android:layout_below="@id/title"
    style="Custom Notification Text" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Add this in your activity onCreate function or inside receiver in case of gcm or fcm (where your notification builds)

```
int icon = R.drawable.ic_launcher;
    long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
    Notification notification = new Notification(icon, "Custom Notification", when);

    NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    RemoteViews contentView = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.custom_notification);
    contentView.setImageViewResource(R.id.image, R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    contentView.setTextViewText(R.id.title, "Custom notification");
    contentView.setTextViewText(R.id.text, "This is a custom layout");
    notification.contentView = contentView;

    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
    notification.contentIntent = contentIntent;

    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR; //Do not clear the notification
    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS; // LED
    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE; //Vibration
    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND; // Sound

    mNotificationManager.notify(1, notification);
```

Comment: It doesn't matter what you are using to create notification. You want text in more than one line. So just make changes in the textview attributes. According to your need.

Comment: this seems more custom for what i want to do

Comment: There is no shortcut for everything. If you want to customise the in built notification of android os. Then you have to create your own.